# Error running code:Segmentation fault (core dumped), what is the reason?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
`typedef struct student {
  char name[80];
  int group;
  int marks[5];
 } student;
void enter(student *stu)
{
  printf("Enter name: ");
  fgets(stu->name, 80, stdin);
  printf("Enter group: ");
  scanf("%d", stu->group);
  printf("Enter marks: ");
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   scanf("%d", stu->marks[i]);
}
int main()
{
  student arr[3];
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    student * temp = &arr[i];
    enter(temp);
  }
  return(0);
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За диагностикой компилятора не следим? По-моему, все современные компиляторы сразу укажут на эти ошибки

```
scanf("%d", &stu->group);
...
scanf("%d", &stu->marks[i]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, в том что не заметил виню себя(был сонный), вот компилятор который я использовал - repl.it

Comment: @B1ZON: Это не компилятор, это чушь какая-то. Возможности посмотреть вывод компилятора там, я так понял, нет?

Comment: Не всегда, а чем вы пользуетесь?

Comment: @B1ZON: Если вы именно про online-компилятор спрашиваете, то: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/